# Join 2 datatable on difference columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have 2 DataTable. I want to use LINQ to join the 2 datatable on difference columns. How to do that?

Table A:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| ACol1  | ACol2 | ACol3 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 | tbA12 | tbA13 |
|      2 | tbA22 | tbA23 |
|      3 | tbA32 | tbA33 |
|      4 | tbA42 | tbA43 |
|      5 | tbA52 | tbA53 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Table B:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| BCol1 | BCol2 | BCol3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     | XX    | tbB13 |
| XX    | 1     | tbB23 |
| XX    | 2     | tbB33 |
| 4     | XX    | tbB43 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

### SQL Query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.BCol3
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.ACol1=b.BCol1 OR a.ACol1=b.BCol2
```

### Expected Result:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| ACol1  | ACol2 | ACol3 | BCol3 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1 | tbA12 | tbA13 | tbB13 |
|      1 | tbA12 | tbA13 | tbB23 |
|      2 | tbA22 | tbA23 | tbB33 |
|      4 | tbA42 | tbA43 | tbB43 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Currently my LINQ query are below:

```
var query1= from rowA in tableA.AsEnumerable()
            join rowB in tableB.AsEnumerable()
            on rowA["ACol1"].ToString() equals rowB["BCol1"].ToString()
            select new
            {
                rowA["ACol1"],
                rowA["ACol2"],
                rowA["ACol3"],
                rowB["BCol3"]
            };

var query2= from rowA in tableA.AsEnumerable()
            join rowB in tableB.AsEnumerable()
            on rowA["ACol1"].ToString() equals rowB["BCol2"].ToString()
            {
                rowA["ACol1"],
                rowA["ACol2"],
                rowA["ACol3"],
                rowB["BCol3"]
            };

var result=query1.Union(query2);
```

Any better idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ support for JOIN with non-trivial conditions is very limited. You could do a cross join + move your condition to where clause.

```
var query1= from rowA in tableA.AsEnumerable()
            from rowB in tableB.AsEnumerable()
            where rowA["ACol1"].ToString() == rowB["BCol1"].ToString()
            || rowA["ACol1"].ToString() == rowB["BCol2"].ToString()
            select new
            {
                rowA["ACol1"],
                rowA["ACol2"],
                rowA["ACol3"],
                rowB["BCol3"]
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var result = from a in tableA.AsEnumerable()
             from b in tableB.AsEnumerable()
             where a.Field<string>("ACol1") == b.Field<string>("BCol1")
                || a.Field<string>("ACol1") == b.Field<string>("BCol2")
             select new
                    {
                        a["ACol1"],
                        a["ACol2"],
                        a["ACol3"],
                        b["BCol3"]
                    };
```

Here is the complete working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IRlrJc), you can copy paste the same in your editor and test because its not supporting `AsEnumerable` in DotNetFiddle.